# Any way to display clock time in the modeline for both the current clock and all accumulated clocks simultaneously?

Tags: org-mode, mode-line, org-clock

The variable `org-clock-mode-line-total` controls whether to show the clocked time of only the current clock or of all accumulated clocks of the current task. However, I'd actually like to show both.

The package `org-pomodoro` displays a pomodoro counter in the modeline in addition to the normal `org-clock` display. However, I don't want the countdown of `org-pomodoro` and want to simply display the time elapsed on the current clock so far, starting from `0:00`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain? If you know how to do it please give me a pointer instead of just downvoting without explanation.

Comment: A bit late but for future travellers: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DisplayTime

Comment: this is useful to have.